# Контактная информация в 2 столбца

Tags: html, css, html5, flexbox

Нужно сверстать блок с контактной информацией таким образом, чтобы слева распологалось название (Адрес, телефон, email и тп), а справа уже сами контакты, то есть вот так:
[image: Блок с контактной информацией]

Пока что моя верстка выглядит следующим образом, это самый максимально приближенный вариант к тому, что должно получиться, из всех, которые были перепробованы..

```css
.contacts {
  width: 375px;
  max-height: 528px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.contacts-list {
  didplay: flex;
  width: 375px;
}

.contact-list-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 375px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
  max-height: 146px;
  padding-top: 23px;
  padding-bottom: 23px;
}

.contacts-header {
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
margin-right: 145px;
min-width: 98px;
margin-right: 47px;
}

.contact-list-link {
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
padding-top: 0px;
}

.list-name-descr {
  line-height: 150%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
   <div class="contacts">
              <ul class="contacts-list">
                <li class="contact-list-item">
                  <h3 class="contacts-header"> Адрес </h3>
                  <p class="list-name-descr"> Москва, улица Юности, дом 5 строение 4, офис 2 </p>
                </li>
                <li class="contact-list-item">
                  <h3 class="contacts-header"> Телефоны </h3>
                  <a class="contact-list-link" href="tel:+74995356434"> +7 (499) 535-64-34 </a>
                  <a class="contact-list-link" href="tel:74950050544"> +7 (495) 005-05-44 </a>
                </li>
              </ul>            
              </div>
```

Но в таком случае ссылки внутри элемента списка располагаются в строку, а не блоком, как нужно было бы

Ещё я пробовала сверстать это, создав 2 списка: один слева для названия контактной инфы, справа - с самой информацией. Но думаю, что этот способ совсем неправильный.

Наверняка есть более изящный способ реализовать блок с контактами, буду рада, если поделитесь (я еще только учусь)

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можно немного поправить то, что сделали вы..

```css
.contacts {
  width: 375px;
  max-height: 528px;
}
.contacts-list {
  width: 375px;
}
.contact-list-item {
  max-width: 375px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
  max-height: 146px;
  padding-top: 23px;
  padding-bottom: 23px;
  display: flex;
}
.contacts-header {
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 145px;
  min-width: 98px;
  margin-right: 47px;
  align-self: center;
}
.contact-list-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #CD9B37;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
.contact-list-link:last-child{
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.list-name-descr {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="contacts">
  <ul class="contacts-list">
    <li class="contact-list-item">
      <h3 class="contacts-header"> Адрес </h3>
      <p class="list-name-descr"> Москва, улица Юности, дом 5 строение 4, офис 2 </p>
    </li>
    <li class="contact-list-item">
      <h3 class="contacts-header"> Телефоны </h3>
      <div id = "tel">  <!-- добавлено -->
        <a class="contact-list-link" href="tel:+74995356434"> +7 (499) 535-64-34 </a>
        <a class="contact-list-link" href="tel:74950050544"> +7 (495) 005-05-44 </a>
      </div><!-- добавлено -->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```